# Oracle SQL: is it possible to reference a column by different name without renaming it

Tags: sql, oracle, tablecolumn

Description of my problem:
For example I have a table "Item" and columns "id", "name", "color", but for some weird reason (please don't ask why - it wasn't me) in the "color" column there is an information about the item and it essentially should be called "description"
A lot of code in the project depends on it and simply renaming the column name will take a tremendous amount of time.

Question:
Is there a way to create some kind of pointer to that column and call it correctly so the sql below will work as expected:

`select i.id, i.name, i.description from Item i`

(it will know that when I type "description" it should look into "color" column.

Comment: `select i.id, i.name, i.color as description from Item i` ?

Comment: Change the column name and then create an alias for the column this way you don't break your old code.

Comment: Since column aliases keep getting mentioned, can I interpret your question to be that you want to be able to write ANY query (updates, inserts, selects) and be able to use "description" and have the database magically know that you really mean the "color" column? E.g., you want to be able to JUST write: `update item set description='abc'`. Correct?

Comment: aquinas, yes you are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no. Long answer: you could create insert and update triggers in Oracle that always keep those column in sync. But, the best thing to do would be to live with it, or rename it and fix your code. Having triggers and storing data in two columns just so your old code doesn't break, but lets your new code use the new column feels like an anti-pattern to me. Frankly, even if Oracle DID have what you were asking for out of the box it STILL feels like an anti pattern. As a developer I would be scratching my head with things like: "Let's see all the places where we ever select `color`." Oops, you just missed all the places where you use `description` instead. It seems VERY confusing to try and go this route. Again, I suggest living with it, or taking the time to update the project with the new correct name

Comment: Thank you! I just wanted to make sure that there is no simple solution to this problem before I take time to change it everywhere in the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an updatable view with properly named column.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180800.aspx

Comment: close, but this is oracle I believe. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/view-updatability.html

Comment: yes, sorry I accidentally tagged this question with "sql-server". I need an answer that works in Oracle sql

Comment: Sadly it will not work in the aforementioned link: " To be more specific, a view is not updatable if it contains any of the following:...  Multiple references to any column of a base table.

Comment: @xQbert Oooops I missed the oracle tag. However,  why is there a need for multiple references to that column?

Comment: Don't think you could have a view and a table named item.  So one would have to be renamed. If the table is renamed, then both columns must exist for existing code to continue to work.  If the View is renamed, then the code he wants to work will not.  It's close but not 100%

Answer (score 0):

This is called a column alias, the example is clunky

```
select BB from
(select column1 AA, column2 BB, column3 CCC from mytable);
```